# Read from Console in F#

Tags: f#, console

Does anyone know if there is a builtin function for reading from the console likewise to the `printfn` function?
The only method I've seen so far is using `System.Console.Read()` but it doesn't feel as functional as using a construct like `printfn` is.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is indeed a shame that there is no such built-in function.  However, as Brian mentioned in a comment on Benjol's answer, it is possible to build a `scanf` function yourself.  Here's a quick sketch of how one might define a `sscanf` variant, although only `%s` placeholders are implemented:

```
open System
open System.Text
open System.Text.RegularExpressions
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let sscanf (pf:PrintfFormat<_,_,_,_,'t>) s : 't =
  let formatStr = pf.Value
  let constants = formatStr.Split([|"%s"|], StringSplitOptions.None)
  let regex = Regex("^" + String.Join("(.*?)", constants |> Array.map Regex.Escape) + "$")
  let matches = 
    regex.Match(s).Groups 
    |> Seq.cast<Group> 
    |> Seq.skip 1
    |> Seq.map (fun g -> g.Value |> box)
  FSharpValue.MakeTuple(matches |> Seq.toArray, typeof<'t>) :?> 't


let (a,b) = sscanf "(%s, %s)" "(A, B)"
let (x,y,z) = sscanf "%s-%s-%s" "test-this-string"
```

Comment: When I needed a more complete version of `sscanf`, it was quite easy to extend this code. See the result here: http://fssnip.net/4I

Comment: @wmeyer : would you be interested in contributing this to FSharpx? https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx

Comment: @wmeyer Problem with this implementation is that it doesn't work so well when you have only one element, because then the `MakeTuple` barfs...

Comment: Quick fix: replace the last `MakeTuple` line with: `if matches.Length = 1 then matches.[0] :?> 't;  else FSharpValue.MakeTuple(matches, typeof<'t>) :?> 't`

Comment: @Rei: Cool! If you want to, you can even fix it directly on fssnip! (I think)

Comment: @wmeyer Oh, didn't notice. Done!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, no.

It would be handy for code golf :)

Comment: It's a shame the `printfn` function itself relies on compiler magic - you couldn't make your own F# `sscanf` quite as nice.

Comment: You can do it, I think. The only magic is that string literals can be coerced to PrintfFormats, at which point the types are manifest: let pf() : PrintfFormat< _ , _ , _ , _ > = "%d %s"

Answer (score 1):

Combination of TryParse() and split/regex is what you can use "out of box".

P.S. i've seen http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/csscanf.aspx and it works ;)