# Console input giving spurious values

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

After trying this simple console input with 5, the result is shown as 53

```
printfn "Enter no. of blocks: "
let nBlock = System.Console.Read()
printfn "entered value is %O" nBlock
```

Tried it on the interactive, still getting wrong results. Any solutions please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should try something like:

```
printfn "Enter no. of blocks: "
let nBlock = System.Console.ReadLine() |> System.Int32.Parse
printfn "entered value is %d" nBlock
```

Explanation:

you code only reads one character - as Lee mentioned
with this you will read a line (ending after you press return) and parse that string into a int.

Remark: maybe you will want to check for a number, you can do this with TryParse:

```
printfn "Enter no. of blocks: "
let nBlock = 
   match System.Console.ReadLine() |> System.Int32.TryParse with
   | true, n -> n
   | false, _ -> -1
printfn "entered value is %d" nBlock
```

Of course you will have to check for the error case (-1) or change it into a option or something.

Answer (score 8):

`System.Console.Read()` returns an `int`, therefore `nBlock` contains the int representation of the input character '5', which is 53. You can convert it back to a `char` using `Convert.ToChar`. Since each character is returned individually, you will need wrapping it into a loop to process the entire input, as described [in this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx).

A better approach is probably to use `Console.ReadLine()` to read then entire line and parse that to an `int`.

Comment: thanks. this just made me miss good old `scanf` more than ever. :-/

Comment: @AruniRC there are several nice implementations of `sscanf`: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2415705/974789) and [two](http://fssnip.net/4I)