# F# - Ask for 3 numbers and then find the minimum?

Tags: f#

I am new to programming so this should be an easy one.

I want to write a code that asks for 3 numbers and then finds the minimum. Something like that:

```
let main(): Unit =
    putline ("Please enter 3 numbers:")
    putline ("First number: ")
    let a = getline ()
    putline ("Second number: ")
    let b = getline ()
    putline("Third number: ")
    let c = getline ()

    if (a<b && a<c) then putline ("Minimum:" + a)
    elif (b<c && b<a) then putline ("Minimum:" + b)
    else putline ("Minimum:" + c)
```

I am sorry if this is terrible but I am still new to this. Also I am not allowed to use the dictionary. Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the F# function `min`, which gives you the minimum of two values.

```ml
min 1 2 // 1
```

To get the minimum of three values you can use it twice:

```ml
min (min a b) c
```

A cleaner way to write this with F# piping is:

```ml
a |> min b |> min c
```

Alternatively, put the items in a list and use `List.min`:

```ml
[ a; b; c ] |> List.min
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your `putline` function.  I'm assuming that this is supposed to take a value and print it to the console with a newline, so the built in F# command to do this is `printfn` and you would use it something like this:

```
let a = 1
printfn "Minimum: %d" a
```

The `%d` gets replaced with the value of `a` as, in this case, a is an integer. You would use %f for a float, %s for a string... the details will all be in the documentation.

So we could write your `putline` function like this:

```
let putline s = printfn "%s" s
```

This function has the following signature, `val putline : s:string -> unit`, it accepts a string and return nothing.  This brings us onto your next problem, you try and say `putline ("Minimum:" + a)`.  This won't work as adding a number and a string isn't allowed, so what you could do is convert `a` to a string and you have several ways to do this:

```
putline (sprintf "Minimum: %d" a)
putline ("Minimum:" + a.ToString())
```

`sprintf` is related to `printfn` but gives you back a string rather than printing to the console, `a.ToString()` converts `a` to a string allowing it to be concatenated with the preceding string.  However just using `printfn` instead of `putline` will work here!

You also have a logic problem, you don't consider the cases where a == b == c, what's the minimum of 1,1,3? Your code would say 3.  Try using `<=` rather than `<`

For reading data from the console, there is already an answer on the site for this [Read from Console in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415705/read-from-console-in-f) that you can look at.

Answer (score 1):

If, for some reason, you decide to expand beyond three numbers, you could consider using `Seq.reduce`

```
let xs = [0;-5;3;4]

xs
|> Seq.reduce min
|> printfn "%d"
// prints -5 to stdout
```

You can use `min` as the reducer because it accepts 2 arguments, which is exactly what `Seq.reduce` expects